# set Index label of stacked bar chart using angularChart.js

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular-chart.js(which uses Chart.js) to create charts in my angular app. 
I want to add values on top of the bars in a bar chart.

can any one provide code with angular js

Html:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 chartview">
                              <div class="column_chart">
                                  <canvas id="weekDriving" class="chart chart-bar" chart-type="StackedBar" chart-labels="vm.week.labels" chart-data="vm.week.data" chart-options="vm.week.options" chart-series="vm.week.series"  chart-colors ="vm.colours"></canvas>
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

code in controller

```
vm.week = {data :[[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]] ,
             labels: ['MA', 'TI', 'ON', 'TO', 'FR', 'LØ', 'SØ'],
             series: ['Km privat', 'Km y0rke'],
             options : {
             legend: {display: true,
                    labels: {
                      fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                      }
                     },
        scales: {
             xAxes: [{
                  stacked: true,
                    }],
            yAxes: [{
                  stacked: true,
                  }]
               } 
      }
    };
```

Comment: is tooltip ok? or you want values to be shown always?

Comment: i want to show total value always

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uh9vw0ao/

Comment: @Sunil, i'm new in angularJS, i dont know hot to use this code in agularjs

Comment: show me what you have tried? add code snippet.

Comment: <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 chartview">
                              <div class="column_chart">
                                  <canvas id="weekDriving" class="chart chart-bar" chart-type="StackedBar" chart-labels="vm.week.labels" chart-data="vm.week.data" chart-options="vm.week.options" chart-series="vm.week.series"  chart-colors ="vm.colours"></canvas>
                              </div>
                            </div>